# establishing USB connection takes > 3 minutes and times out, charging works

Tags: usb, linux

Some time ago I've been able to connect my "Smart"phone to my Ubuntu 14.04 PC as mass storage device with an micro USB cable hitting the ~"Activate USB storage" (translated) button in the notifiaction pull-down panel which appeared after the cable has been plugged in. Now, establishing an USB connection is tried for > 3 minutes and then times out; the animated waiting icon (spinning circle in which the button to activate the USB storage is transformed to) changes back to the button to activate the storage. Some infos:

- occurs 100 % of the tries
- restart doesn't help
- cable seems fine because charging works
- Android 4.0.4 on SansuiCosmic SP 1001 trying to connect to Ubuntu 14.04 with Linux 3.15.9 without problems with USB experienced so far.

Comment: I've never seen an "establish connection" button, could you get a screenshot of this? What mode are you trying to connect in? ADB/MTP/PTP/Mass device?

Comment: "cable seems fine ***because charging works***": disagreed *on the reasoning*. USB plugs have at least 4 (some have 5) pins in use. 2 are for power, the other two for data. So if one of the data connections got broken, it would still charge fine. // Have you tried a different cable?